# 555 timer charge pump with feedback

Tags: operational-amplifier, 555, charge-pump, mc34063

In the circuit I am working on there is a requirement to create 30V DC source for a very light load (couple of mA max). I am aware that there a specialized ICs that can do that but I would like to achieve that with the parts that I already have.

What I came up with is this:
[image]
The idea is that 555 IC configured in astable mode drives a voltage multipler (configured as tripler on the schematic), a fraction of output voltage is compared with known source (1/3rd of 15V) via an op amp and the amplified error is fed into NPN so that when base voltage is ~0 control and reset pins of 555 IC are triggered.

Simulation in LTSpice does produce a desired output:
[image]
And a closer loot at 555out:
[image]
[image]

The 15V and -15v are generated at the same time with two MC34063 hence they are not stable at the startup:
[image]
[image]

What I was wondering is:

1. Is there any reason this circuit would fail in the real life?
2. Are there any possible improvements that might simplify/improve the schematic?

Comment: I've not looked over the circuit much. But I do notice that perhaps an LM239 (or LM139 or LM339), if you have one, already includes a nice open-collector output and might be able to replace all that 'error amplifier' and 'feedback' stuff. Apparently, you have +/-15 V that are *also* starting up. It would be very easy to use another LM239 (there's four available in the IC) to monitor the 15 V rail and enable the circuit, if you wanted that feature.

Comment: @jonk , thank you. Simulation with LM339 works like a charm. I have   an equivalent chip 1401SA1 at my disposal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C14 is useless, you only need the other 4 caps for this tripler and Cout can also be 0.1UF if you raise the frequency from 10 kHz.

The voltage ratio will follow the transformer impedance ratio rules of Load/source ^2 so with 30V and 10k load the unregulated voltage will drop from 45V-diode drops by the amplified source impedance of 9x plus diode impedance. Effectively you need a source impedance of < 100 ohms or or so to drop 43V to 30V with load of 3 mA. (Guestimate)

I don't see any reliability issues but definitely see cost/simplification opportunities.

Answer (score 2):

Using the TL431 for the error feedback control may simplify the design.

[image: 555 boost]

[image: Start]

[image: Output response.]

[image: Step zoom]

No load starting.

[image: No load]